# How Can I change the filed color while approve manually in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end.How Can I change the `green color` to `tollerence` `159.06` in table as a manually. [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RN7GCkHSwore1y5PP8bS?p=preview)

- Look at My plunker to refference.
- What we did has, we have used `ng-show` in the tollerrence filed if the value is `greaterthan` `>` to 100 it's should need to highlight has a `red color`.
- If the value is `lesserthan` `<` to 100 means it's should need to highlight has a `green color`.
- what we exactly looking for if the `tollerence` value is `greaterthan` `>` 100 means it's highlighting like `red color`, so once it's approved means this value is need to change has a `green color`, so how we would to do the changes as a manual,
- Any idea about the solution, please help us..

**My Html:-**

```
<td > <p ng-show="{{(mani.invoice_quantity *1) + (mani.conversion_rate *1) | number:2}}>100" style="background-color: red;">{{(mani.invoice_quantity *1) + (mani.conversion_rate *1) | number:2}}</p>

 <p ng-show="{{(mani.invoice_quantity *1) + (mani.conversion_rate *1) | number:2}}<100" style="background-color: Green;">{{(mani.invoice_quantity *1) + (mani.conversion_rate *1) | number:2}}</p></td>
```

**My data:-**

```
$scope.sryarndebitnote = [
    {
    "_id": "57ac1b6d82e1c5940ac3c730",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-08-11T06:30:05.118Z",
    "shipment_id": "57ac19b982e1c5940ac3c72f",
    "conversion_rate": "62.04",
    "invoice_value_fob_currency": "Rs",
    "invoice_value_fob": "300.231",
    "invoice_quantity_unit": "KG",
    "invoice_quantity": "37",
    "invoice_date": "2016-08-17",
    "supplier_name": "Msd",
    "buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
    },

    {
    "_id": "57b5af69df0475401f644b2e",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-08-18T12:51:53.671Z",
    "shipment_id": "57b5af5bdf0475401f644b2d",
    "conversion_rate": "62.06",
    "exclusive": true,
    "invoice_value_fob": "400.343",
    "invoice_quantity": "97",
    "supplier_name": "Msd",
    "buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
    },]
```

- I have created my plunker to referrence :- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Ts4hNMKpxEQrKbjeMHP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i would recommend you to use [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead of this `ngShow`. if you want to change it manualy you can add a button and add a change the value of the

```
<td>
    <p ng-style="{'background-color': (mani.invoice_quantity *1) + (mani.conversion_rate *1) > 100 || mani.approved ? 'green' : 'red'}">{{(mani.invoice_quantity *1) + (mani.conversion_rate *1) | number:2}}</p>
    <button ng-click="mani.approved = true">Approve</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, can you please update this in plunker as well to know the solution, bcoz I have tried but  unable to get the solution...thanks...

Comment: Thanks for your updated plunker, I will try this in my local host and update you, thanks a lot....

Comment: Yeah sure , thanks it's really useful to us, but once it's approved or green color filed values means I want to `Hide` that button , so any idea or solution regarding this and plunker please.....how to `hide` that `approve button` if the field vlaue is green color.

Comment: just add `ng-hide` to the button.. I updated the plnkr

Comment: Thanks a lot.... then if we refresh the page again it's showing like red color value, so how we can save it , do you have any idea regarding this?... how to save ?, For example: - if we click approve to change the color like green , if reload the page the value sholud need to be in green , it's displaying red color , so how to save it ?... if you know the solution please help us....